# Reading data from the JSON object

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have JSON data in a file **json_format.py** as follows:

```
{
    "name"      : "ramu",
    "place"     : "hyd",
    "height"    : 5.10,
    "list"      : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    "tuple"     : (0,1,2),
    "colors"    : {"mng":"white","aft" : "blue","night":"red"},
    "car"       : "None",
    "bike"      : "True",
}
```

I'm reading the above with this code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open (r'C:/PythonPrograms\Json_example/json_format.py') as jobj:
    fp = jobj.readlines()  
    b = json.dumps(fp)                # ---> I get string 
    print(type(b))    
    c = json.loads(b)
    print(type(c))                    # ---> List
    pprint(c)
    print(c[0])
    pprint(c["name"])
```

Now, I would like to access the JSON object as `c['name']` and the output should be `ramu`.
Since `c` is a list, I can't do so. How can I read my JSON data so that I can access it with keys?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're storing your JSON in a `.py` file?

Comment: Yes ! I need to all constants to be in separate file .

Comment: No, I mean as opposed to a `.json` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're effectively doing `c = json.loads(json.dumps(jobj.readlines()))` when you just need:

```
c = json.load(jobj)

print(c["name"]) # ramu
```

Also, your JSON is malformed.

- There are no tuples in JSON: `"tuple" : (0,1,2),`
- Your last item should not end with a comma: `"bike" : "True",`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion ! But my final intention is to read the JSON object like keys.